# HSV / RGB color space conversion

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb, hsv, hue

I found this code in this forum but Im having doubts with the code.

1. in this code snippet  "int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;" why the complete answer is modulus by 6? (%6)
2. why is " value = value * 255 " value is multiplied by 255?

   im reffering to this research paper (p-15 , p-16) and same algorithmic is discussed but I found these differences.

   http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/coloureq.pdf

   ```
   public static Color ColorFromHSV(double hue, double saturation, double value)
   {
       int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;
       double f = hue / 60 - Math.Floor(hue / 60);

       value = value * 255;
       int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
       int p = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - saturation));
       int q = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - f * saturation));
       int t = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation));

       if (hi == 0)
       return Color.FromArgb(255, v, t, p);
       else if (hi == 1)
       return Color.FromArgb(255, q, v, p);
       else if (hi == 2)
       return Color.FromArgb(255, p, v, t);
       else if (hi == 3)
       return Color.FromArgb(255, p, q, v);
       else if (hi == 4)
       return Color.FromArgb(255, t, p, v);
       else
       return Color.FromArgb(255, v, p, q);
    }

   public void convertToHSV(Color color, out double hue, out double saturation, out double value)
   {
       int max = Math.Max(color.R, Math.Max(color.G, color.B));
       int min = Math.Min(color.R, Math.Min(color.G, color.B));

       hue = color.GetHue();
       saturation = (max == 0) ? 0 : 1d - (1d * min / max);
       value = max / 255d;

   }
   ```

Comment: is it because hue changes it color in cylindrical coordinates? guys help me out

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding

   int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;

Hue might be represented as larger than 360 or smaller than 0, if there are color transformations involved in other pieces of code that do not make sure to divide mod 360. 
If you are 100% sure that all other functions are going to return Hue within [0,360] then the modulo 6 is not needed.

1. In HSV, Value is typically normalized to the [0,1] continuous interval, whereas in RGB in the discrete [0,255] interval. Hence both:

   ```
     value = value * 255;
   ```

and

```
      value = max / 255d;
```